# Rspec Mocking and return value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to integrate my application with the Sendgrid api. For example, when a user registers add the user's email to Sendgrid.

As of now I have the following tests:

```
context "painter registers" do
      let(:new_painter) {FactoryGirl.build(:painter)}
      it "#add_email_to_sendgrid is called" do
        new_painter.should_receive(:add_email_to_sendgrid)
        new_painter.save
      end
      it "Sendgrid#add_email called and should return true" do
        new_painter.email = "nobody-sendgrid@painterprofessions.com"
        Sendgrid.should_receive(:add_email).with("nobody-sendgrid@painterprofessions.com").and_return(true)
        new_painter.save
      end
    end
```

In my Painter model I have the following:

```
 after_create :add_email_to_sendgrid

def add_email_to_sendgrid
   Sendgrid.add_email(self.email)
  end
```

lib/sendgrid.rb

```
module Sendgrid
    def self.add_email(email_address)
      return false
    end
end
```

Everything is working up until the return value of Sendgrid.add_email.

I can change the add_email methods return value to anything and the test will still pass.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is confusion in the way you read:

```
Sendgrid.should_receive(:foo).with(args).and_return(bar)
```

You can actually return whatever you want, this is not an expectation, it's just a convenient way to simulate a service.

So:

- yes, you can return anything you want.
- yes, your spec will pass whatever value is returned since you do not spec anything related to it

I guess you expct the fail to fail somehow because the `after_create` returns false, if so, it's kind of awkward to have a creation depend on an external service.

Comment: Hi, I think you're right. I do not want creation dependent on the service. I just want to make sure it's called after registering. If there's other problems then I should probably just log them. It seems it was a problem with my approach then?